# How to find the minimum value for all columns between the most recent 12 rows of records

Tags: mysql

The following code does not seem to work:

```
SELECT * FROM econ_x ORDER BY * LIMIT 13,1
```

Comment: Pls provide some sample data and expected outcome based on the sample data, and also explain what was the exact error message or unexpected behaviour you encountered.

Comment: It returns me a value, but it is not the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the minimum column in each of the most recent 12 rows, then use `MIN()` to get the minimum of all those values.

```
SELECT MIN(x.smallest_col)
FROM (SELECT LEAST(col1, col2, col3, col4, ...) AS smallest_col
      FROM econ_x
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 12) AS x
```